# Query to fill in missing denormalized column values for rows using a key & at least one good row?

Tags: mysql, sql, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, talend

I'm collecting data daily in a denormalized table and sometimes my descriptive data doesn't get captured (I will show an example of the kind of data that results)

*By the way, I *am* trying to determine how to improve the collection system, I don't want it to get too complicated though... The reality might be that I just have to live with some data getting missed for now

Since it's quite often the case that only a few of the days for a given ID have missing data, I'm hoping to perhaps run a SQL query at the end of my process (a Talend DI job) to fill in the holes based on the key (i.e., the ID)

Here is the kind of data that occurs a small % of the time:

```
+---------+------------+------------------+------+------------------+
|   Id    |    date    |     category     | year |       manu       |
+---------+------------+------------------+------+------------------+
| 5682540 | 2014-05-02 | NULL             | NULL | NULL             |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-03 | NULL             | NULL | NULL             |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-04 | NULL             | NULL | NULL             |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-05 | NULL             | NULL | NULL             |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-06 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-07 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-08 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-09 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-10 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-11 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-12 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-13 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-14 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-15 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-16 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-17 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-18 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-19 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-20 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-21 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
+---------+------------+------------------+------+------------------+
```

And my desired result after running the query would of course be:

```
+---------+------------+------------------+------+------------------+
|   Id    |    date    |     category     | year |       manu       |
+---------+------------+------------------+------+------------------+
| 5682540 | 2014-05-02 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-03 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-04 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-05 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-06 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-07 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-08 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-09 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-10 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-11 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-12 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-13 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-14 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-15 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-16 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-17 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-18 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-19 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-20 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
| 5682540 | 2014-05-21 | Class A - Diesel | 2007 | Thor Motor Coach |
+---------+------------+------------------+------+------------------+
```

As for what I have tried so far...

Using Talend Open Studio I designed a job that successfully fixed the values by creating a copy of the table, and then using the original table as both the main source and the lookup source, applying a JOIN, [as per this recommendation on the Talendforge forum](http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=36450)

However, I really don't want to have to use a whole new table just to fix these – not that this is necessarily what the forum thread respondent implied, but rather this is what I came up with to test – as this is a rather large table, and having two copies just doesn't "sit right" with me

I had asked the respondent if it would work to use the same table for all three positions in the subjob (i.e., the main input, lookup input and output) but didn't hear back - I can test this, but it still seems a bit odd, not my preferred solution

Again, I'm hoping there is a SQL query that would solve this issue for me that I could run at the end of my Talend job in a separate component

To actually get my lookup table results (i.e., data with no holes in it), I am using the following:

```
SELECT 
  `myTable`.`Id`, 
  MAX(`myTable`.`category`), 
  MAX(`myTable`.`year`), 
  MAX(`myTable`.`manu`)
FROM `myTable`
GROUP BY Id
HAVING MAX(`myTable`.`category`) IS NOT NULL
AND MAX(`myTable`.`year`) != 0
AND MAX(`myTable`.`manu`) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE myTable AS t1
JOIN (SELECT Id,
             MAX(category) AS category,
             MAX(year) AS year,
             MAX(manu) AS manu
      FROM myTable
      WHERE category IS NOT NULL
        AND year IS NOT NULL
        AND manu IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY Id) AS t2
ON t1.Id = t2.Id
SET t1.category = t2.category,
    t1.year = t2.year,
    t1.manu = t2.manu
WHERE t1.category IS NULL AND t1.year IS NULL AND t1.manu IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I'll run it against a test copy of my table and report back :)